# towers of hanoi in common lisp

Tags: recursion, common-lisp, towers-of-hanoi

I think this is going to be a vague question because I don't know exactly what I am doing in the first place but here it goes.

I have to do a towers of hanoi problem in common lisp using lists. Basically a function takes a list of strings (names) and then moves them from peg A to peg C using peg B for storage, keeping them in the same order as they were in the list.

I have never used lisp before and I find the syntax very hard to understand. 
This is my code so far
goo function is the hanoi work

```
(defparameter A '())
(defparameter B '())
(defparameter C '())


(defun findPeg (p1 p2) (cond ((= 0 (- 3 p1 p2))A)  
    ((= 1 (- 3 p1 p2))B) ((= 2 (- 3 p1 p2))C)))

(defun getnum (x) (cond ((equalp x A) 0)((equalp x B)1)((equalp x C) 2)))

(defun hanoi (x) (defparameter A x) (setlength A)(goo len A C B))

(defun setlength(x) (defparameter len (list-length x)))


(defun goo (leng from to via) 

    (cond ((= leng 1)(push (pop A) C)) ;base case


((goo (1- leng) from via to)(push (pop A)  B) ;say/do something i think


((goo (1- leng) via to from)(push (pop B) C) ;say/do something i think


))))
```

My problem is with the recursive calls. I am very confused as to what exactly I should be doing. I know I obviously have to move the first string in the first list to another peg, but I don't know which peg or even how to manipulate the lists. I feel like I should be using the variables that were passed into the goo function, but I cant figure out how to edit them because when I change them in the function the variables outside do not change.

Right now I am running into the error

*** - SYSTEM::%EXPAND-FORM: (GOO (1- LENG) FROM VIA TO) should be a lambda expression

This is a recursive call so I don't know why it is saying that.

Basically I just want some tips or tricks on where do continue or ever where to restart because I don't even know if my approach is a good one.
Anything is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, using defparameter inside a DEFUN is almost never the right thing to do.

If you want to have a lexically-scoped variable, use LET (or simply name your formal parameters as you'd like them named).

Second, you have something on the form `((fun arg ..) (fun arg ...))` inside your GOO function. You want to lose the outermost parentheses.